# How does one use the equalizer inside of a Foundation modal?

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a website based on the Foundation library. I'm creating an About "page" on my website by using a modal, and attempting to equalize the three different panes inside of the modal, like so:

```
  <div id="aboutPage" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <h1>About</h1>
    <div class="row" data-equalizer>
      <div class="large-4 columns panel" data-equalizer-watch>
        <h2>About This Site</h2>
        <p>This site is intended to provide a resource for people learning to program in Swift.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="large-4 columns panel" data-equalizer-watch>
        <h2>What's Coming Up</h2>
        <p>We're working on smoothing over some glitches with the brand new Issue tracking systems. We also have some exciting updates planned involving this site's mobile version.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="large-4 columns panel" data-equalizer-watch>
        <h2>Using the Help Menu</h2>
        <p>The Help menu quickly lets you contact Support to address issues which may present themselves as you program in Swift. If a representative is not available when you submit your question, we will address your issue as soon as possible. You will
          receive a notification badge when the issue has been resolved.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal" id="x">&#215;</a>
  </div>
```

However, when I viewed the modal, the panels were not equalized. This was also true on several other modals on which I attempted to do the same thing. Despite that, I was able to successfully equalize the panels outside of the modal. Is this a bug/feature related to the modal, and if so, is there any way around it?

Comment: Probably because equilizer will finish equilizing before the reveal modal layout is created.

Comment: Try setting heights in css - you can use media queries to make that responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your Reveal Modal opened you will need to recalculate the height of the Equalizer panels.

```
// Once the Reveal Modal has been opened . . .
$(document).on('opened.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
    // Force Foundation to recalculate the Equalizer panel heights
    Foundation.libs.equalizer.reflow();
});
```

Here is a working example in [codepen](http://codepen.io/adam-huffman/full/EDlcp).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Even though this works in your demo, for some reason it does not work on my site. Just to clarify, my site contains an accordion, is wrapped in the necessary off-canvas tags (to display an off-canvas menu to mobile devices), and has 3 different modals that need to be equalized. Could any of this be why the solution isn't working?

Comment: Your configuration would have an effect on whether or not it would worked. I also assumed you were using Foundation 5.4.6. Are you able to share more of your HTML for the community to look at?

Comment: Turns out my script was running before I initialized Foundation, and now it works properly. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

In Foundation 6, I was having the same issue. Here is the solution that ultimately worked for me.

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
      $('.reveal').on('open.zf.reveal', function() {
      //force equalizer to fire AFTER modal has finished opening
      Foundation.reInit('equalizer');
  });
</script>
```